Smoothing values with known monthly plans
I have some  planned monthly values, and the java model runs by the hour. Within a month (except for smoothing periods), the flow is constant   I need to make a smooth one. (Smoothed) transition within 1 day of the next month from the old hourly speed values to the new ones, so that the plan is exactly fulfilled for each month. At the same time, if the plan for t + 1 month is zero, then it is necessary to smoothly drop to zero on the last day of the month t
.
All plans for any horizon are known in advance.
The number of smoothing intervals is a user parameter.
Has anyone seen similar algorithms in java?
I read internet and this forum

Yura, this is an interesting problem, which doesn't seem to have a conventional solution yet. The simplest solution I have seen is to construct a cubic spline for the cumulative monthly time series, and then differentiate it. I.e., construct a series m(1), m(1) + m(2), m(1) + m(2) + m(3), ... where m(k) is the k'th monthly value, then fit a cubic spline to that. Then find the derivative of that cumulative spline, and evaluate that at each hour. If you are interested, I can find some references.

Identify Key Variables:

Total monthly values.
Smoothing intervals (e.g., a day or hours in the last day of the month).
Monthly to hourly flow conversion factor.

Smooth Transition Function:
For the smoothing transition, a polynomial (e.g., cubic or higher) can provide a gradual approach to the new value. Interpolating functions like cubic splines or linear interpolation over a defined interval (such as the last day) can help.
Hourly Flow Calculation:

Divide the monthly value evenly across the hours in the month (for constant flow periods).

For smoothing, use an interpolation approach to gradually shift the hourly flow from the old to the new value across the defined transition period. For a smooth drop to zero, consider a decay function (like exponential decay) over the final interval.


Implementing this in Java might look like:
public double[] smoothTransition(double currentMonthlyValue, double nextMonthlyValue, int hoursInMonth, int smoothingIntervalHours) {
    double[] hourlyFlow = new double[hoursInMonth];
    double constantFlowRate = currentMonthlyValue / (hoursInMonth - smoothingIntervalHours);
    for (int i = 0; i < hoursInMonth - smoothingIntervalHours; i++) {
        hourlyFlow[i] = constantFlowRate;
    }
    double transitionFactor = (nextMonthlyValue - currentMonthlyValue) / smoothingIntervalHours;
    for (int i = hoursInMonth - smoothingIntervalHours; i < hoursInMonth; i++) {
        hourlyFlow[i] = currentMonthlyValue + transitionFactor * (i - (hoursInMonth - smoothingIntervalHours));
    }
    return hourlyFlow;
}

This code provides a simple linear interpolation for smoothing, which can be enhanced with cubic splines or more complex transitions if needed.
